# Apigee Edge SSL Handshake failed for TCP

Tags: apigee

I'm using Apigee to connect to an endpoint via a proxy, and I have configured the target endpoint URL as 'https://hostname/api'. However, I'm getting an SSL handshake error with the following message: 'SSL Handshake failed for TCP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443'.

I'm new to Apigee and not sure how to fix this issue. I tried the same setup with Nginx and resolved the issue with the '**proxy_ssl_server_name on**' configuration option.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue with Apigee would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <SSLInfo>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
     </SSLInfo>
    <URL>https://xxxxxx.com</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTTPTargetConnection configured at target endpoint? Do mask whatever details you think are unnecessary.

Comment: I'm assuming you are going with 1 way tls. Do you have Apigee certificate chain in your backend server's trust store?

Comment: Hi Yes, It is a one-way TLS. I don't think there is a need to have apigee certificate chain in the backend server's trust store

Comment: How else would your backend verify if the caller is a trusted one? Also, please refer section titled "SSL Handshake Failures" (page 45) of this link - https://docs.apigee.com/static/files/ApigeeEdgeTroubleshootingGuide.pdf. Could help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all thank you very much for your answers we are able to find out that this issue is related to F5, not Apigee. F5 setup is not correctly configured to support the SNI validation part